# LifetimeManager in Builder Strategy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to implement a disposing transient lifetime manager for Unity version 3.5. The problem is that I don't know how to access the `LifetimeManager` in the `PostTearDown`,etc. steps of the `BuilderStrategy` class. `context.Lifetime` works fine in Unity 2.

Basically I have the following:

```
Container = new UnityContainer();
Container.AddNewExtension<DisposableStrategyExtension>();
Container.RegisterType<ITest, Test>(new DisposingTransientLifetimeManager());


public class DisposingLifetimeStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            base.PreBuildUp(context);
            // context.Lifetime.Count == 0 here and in all other methods.
            // In version 2 of unity this is set.
        }
    // implement rest of methods, but context.Lifetime.Count is 0 in all of them too.


public class DisposingTransientLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager
    // implement abstract methods minimally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the lifetime manager from the policy list:

```
public class DisposingLifetimeStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        ILifetimePolicy lifeTime = context.Policies.Get<ILifetimePolicy>(context.BuildKey);               
        base.PreBuildUp(context);
    }

    public override void PreTearDown(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        // Assumes registration name is null
        var buildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(context.Existing.GetType());
        ILifetimePolicy lifeTime = context.Policies.Get<ILifetimePolicy>(buildKey);
        base.PreTearDown(context);
    }
}
```

If you are calling IUnityContainer.Teardown(obj) then the PreTearDown and PostTearDown methods will not know the name of the resolved object.  That may not matter as long as a default (null) registration exists (since I assume you just want to cast the object to an `IDisposable` and then Dispose the object).